# Gulp.js sass css compiling very slow

Tags: sass, gulp

I'm new to using gulpjs. Before I was using SASS and Compass. I followed this tutorial http://ericlbarnes.com/setting-gulp-bower-bootstrap-sass-fontawesome/

It all works fine, but the sass compiles very slowly which is annoying.

I This is my code:

```
  var gulp = require('gulp'),         
    sass = require('gulp-ruby-sass')     
    notify = require("gulp-notify")     
    bower = require('gulp-bower');

var config = {
         sassPath: './scss',
         bowerDir: './bower_components'     
}


gulp.task('css', function() {     
    return gulp.src(config.sassPath + '/style.scss')
             .pipe(sass({
                 style: 'compressed',
                 loadPath: [
                     './scss',
                     config.bowerDir + '/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/stylesheets',
                     config.bowerDir + '/fontawesome/scss',
                 ]
             })     
            .on("error", notify.onError(function (error) {
                     return "Error: " + error.message;
                 })))     
             .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/css'));     
});

gulp.task('bower', function() {     
    return bower()
             .pipe(gulp.dest(config.bowerDir))     
});

gulp.task('icons', function() {     
    return gulp.src(config.bowerDir + '/fontawesome/fonts/**.*')     
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/fonts'));     
});


// Rerun the task when a file changes
     gulp.task('watch', function() {
         gulp.watch(config.sassPath + '/**/*.scss', ['css']);     
});

          gulp.task('default', ['bower', 'icons', 'css']);
```

Comment: Without reading into it too much, using the Ruby gem is known to be much slower than using [`gulp-sass`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sass) to compile via `libsass`.

Comment: thanks I will check that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I swapped to gulp-sass as suggested.

My code:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
sass = require('gulp-sass')
notify = require("gulp-notify")     
bower = require('gulp-bower');

var config = {     
    sassPath: './scss',
         bowerDir: './bower_components'     
}

gulp.task('css', function() {
        gulp.src(config.sassPath + '/style.scss')
            .pipe(sass({     
                    style: 'compressed',
                    includePaths: [     './scss', 
                    config.bowerDir + '/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/stylesheets',      
                    config.bowerDir + '/fontawesome/scss',      ]     
                })
                .on("error", notify.onError(function(error) {     
                    return "Error: " + error.message;     
                })))     

             .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/css'));     
});



gulp.task('bower', function() {     
    return bower()     .pipe(gulp.dest(config.bowerDir))     
});

gulp.task('icons', function() {     
    return gulp.src(config.bowerDir + '/fontawesome/fonts/**.*')     
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/fonts'));     
});


// Rerun the task when a file changes
     
gulp.task('watch', function() {     
    gulp.watch(config.sassPath + '/**/*.scss', ['css']);     
});

          
gulp.task('default', ['bower', 'icons', 'css']);
```